# How to verify the AWS NitroTPM endorsement key (EK Certificate)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tpm

Amazon AWS announced their own [TPM](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ec2-now-supports-nitrotpm-and-uefi-secure-boot/) in their *Nitro* Systems, aka the *NitroTPM*.
They seem to be very quiet about the technical details though.

I am interested in using the `NitroTPM` for remote attestation.
I use the `tpm2_tools` to interact with the TPM.
Reading transient, permanent or persistent values seems not to reveal any EK Certificates.

```
$ sudo tpm2_getcap handles-persistent
$ sudo tpm2_getcap handles-permanent
```

Some other cloud providers like azure publish their certificate hierarchie but I couln't find anything on the side of AWS.

Am I missing something or does AWS really not provide any technical information regarding their Endorsement Certificates?

Answer (score 1):

I recently contacted AWS support about this issue, this is the response I received:

> I understand that you are looking to retrieve the public component of the endorsement key from outside the instance or retrieve a signed endorsement key certificate from inside the instance. At this time, no EK cert exists for NitroTPM on EC2. I can, however, confirm that the responsible internal team is working on this and it is a priority feature on their roadmap. An ETA has not been provided as yet. The idea is to provide an EC2 API that allows retrieval of the endorsement key.

Answer (score 0):

A TPM typically provides an Endorsement Certificate (chain) in its non-volatile (NV) memory. This is specified in the [TCG EK Credential Profile](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_IWG_EKCredentialProfile_v2p3_r2_pub.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A68%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C305%2C0%5D):

- EK certificate (ECC NIST P256): NV index `0x01c0000a`
- EK Certificate (RSA 2048): NV index `0x01c00002`

You also want to have a look at the [tpm2_getekcertificate](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_getekcertificate.1.md) tool.

Comment: I have tried all these methods but none would work. Here are my results:

1. Reading from NVRAM: making use of `tpm2_nvread` does not yield results. Neither trying to read the entire NVRAM with `tpm2_nvread` nor searching at the specified offsets in from the standard with `tpm2_nvread -Co 0x01c0000a`

2. The `tpm2_getekcertificate` does not yield results either. Since the chip is manufactured by Amazon and not Intel, the only valid option would be to use `tpm2_getekcertificate -o ECcert.bin` which fails